# How to split by space but preserve string literals with spaces

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am writing  a VB program for lex analyzer (a small code) that will identify keywords, identifiers ,  and Strings. I am taking a string  and then converting splitting it into words
this is what i tried

```
    For Each line As String In txt_source.Text.Split(new String() _
                           {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.None)  

        'Loop through each word in that line 
          For Each word As String In line.split()
            If myKeywordList.Contains(word) then
              txt_output.Text &= word & "is a keyword" 
           ElseIf IS_an_Identifier(word) Then
              txt_output.Text &= word & "is an identifier"
            ElseIf word.StartsWith("""") And word.EndsWith("""") Then                       
                  txt_output.Text &= word & "is a string literal"
             End if

          Next 
  Next
```

this works well . the split function splits the string into separate elements based on a (space)

but i want the split function to ignore the String literals. for example
 when i enter a string literal like "now is the time"
i don't want it to be divided into substrings instead i want it to be returned as a word. is this possible????

Comment: What kind of string literals do you need to support? Like `"Some ""quoted text"""`?

Comment: i want to preserve string literals with spaces that are enclosed in double quotes for example "this is a string literal"..

Comment: But how is `"` represented in your string literals? Like in VB.NET or C? How are they escaped in your input?

Comment: i am using  a text box to enter the string in this format   "string literal "

Comment: Then it is not a string literal, it is a string enclosed with double quotes but with no double quotes inside. You need [`"[^"]*"|\S+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%7c%5cS%2b&i=Text+and%0d%0a%22some+string%22+here+%22+%22).

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: i get error expression expected. on this line.  For Each lin As String In Regex.Split(txt_source.Text, "[^"]*"|\S+)    am i missing something

Comment: Of course, to use a `"` inside a VB.NET string literal, you need to double the double quote. `"""[^""]*""|\S+"`. However, you cannot use `Regex.Split`. You need to use `Regex.Matches`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a *matching* approach rather than *splitting*, to match substrings inside double quotes (`"[^"]*"`) or (`|`) strings of non-whitespace chars (`\S+`).

```
"[^"]*"|\S+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%7c%5cS%2b&i=Text+and%0d%0a%22some+string%22+here+%22+%22).

Also, see the [VB.NET demo](http://ideone.com/G0KERy):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Collections
Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim s As String = "Text    ""inside quotes"" here"
        Dim results As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(s, """[^""]*""|\S+")
        For Each m As Match In results
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

A one-liner with LINQ:

```
Dim results As List(Of String) = Regex.Matches(s, """[^""]*""|\S+").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for giving the time man. i really appreciate it ... this is a good place to start what i am looking for

Comment: Note that `"[^"]*"` will match substrings like `"`, then any 0+ chars other than `"`, and then a `"`. You might want to use `"(?:""|[^"])*"` or `"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"` to match VB-like string literals that have double-quote-escaped double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will remember that for the future. Thanks.

Comment: `\S` matches *any non-whitespace* symbols including `-`, `+`, `/` and `*`.